Get the title details of opened child window in parent window in Flutter Web using Javascript
I am opening the new tab from flutter by using
js.Method.call()

to call the js function and open the new tab.Below is the JS code
function openURLAndListen(url) {
  var openedWindow = window.open(url, '_self');

  // Check if we can access the new tab
  if (openedWindow && openedWindow.document) {
    // Function to periodically check the title
    var checkTitle = function() {
      console.log('New tab title: ' + openedWindow.document.title);
    };

    // Poll the new tab's title every 500 milliseconds
    var titlePollInterval = setInterval(checkTitle, 500);

    // Stop polling when the window is closed or navigated away
    openedWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
      clearInterval(titlePollInterval);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Cannot access new tab due to same-origin policy');
  }
} 

I am actually opening the payment gateway url and after payment done, the callBack url should called. In that the details of transaction Id and other parts is present in the title of the tab. So I want it to get the details from title.
In this code I just want it to display the result on the console.
I had tried lots of JS code to get the title details back but not succed. Let me know if this thing is possible or not.
